# npm WARN install Refusing to install hapi as a dependency of itself

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I tried to do the following (per instructions from [official site](http://hapijs.com/)):

- `mkdir hapi && cd hapi`
- `npm init`
- `npm install hapi --save`

But this gives me an error like this:

> npm WARN install Refusing to install hapi as a dependency of itself

Now, I made a new test folder called `hapiTest` and repeated the commands and then everything worked fine.

I tried the same process with a folder `gulp` and `npm install gulp --save`, and got the same error, so my conclusion is that I can't have the name of the folder be the same as the package that I want to install, but can someone back this statement up with some official documentation?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

When you did the command `npm init`, there were probably some relevant questions you needed to answer. Specifically, the name of your module. When you use `npm init`, it assumes you want the name of the module you're creating to be called the name of the folder it is in.

So it's not the name of the ***folder*** that is stopping you from installing the dependency, it is the name of the ***npm module*** that you are creating.

Open the resulting `package.json` within your `hapi` directory, and rename the module to something other than `hapi`. Here's an example 'package.json' that works, even when residing in a folder called *hapi*:

```
{
  "name": "hapi-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "hapi": "^7.5.2"
  }
}
```

**Added Note**

I've not been able to find any documentation thus-far explaining this phenomena in the context of npm; though it is a bit of a no-brainer. Requiring modules with the same name within the same application would conflict with the [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS) philosophy.

Comment: I named the folder initially with the same name as that of the module I wanted to install. I ignored `npm init` instructions. I encountered the error despite changing the directory name. Thanks @shennan, now that I've changed the name in `package.json`, the world is at peace :)

Comment: Ran into the same thing, the name of the package was the same as the module.

Answer (score 10):

The name of your module is same as the module you are trying to install. NPM thinks that you are installing the module to itself. Change the name of your module and it will install perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

**Reason**
 Module name is same with library name

**Solution**

1. Change the module name to something else
2. Change 'name' in package.json

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be simply explained as follows 
***the name of your package or module in `package.json` cannot be same as that of the package or module you are trying to install***.

Here `hapi` is the name of your module and  you are trying to install a module with name `hapi` with `npm install hapi --save`

Answer (score 0):

**This was my initial code**

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

*which threw error*

```
npm WARN package.json react@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json react@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json react@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN install Refusing to install react as a dependency of itself
```

then i renamed the name from react to react_app and my code looks like

```
{
  "name": "react_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

then it worked