# npm WARN install Refusing to install smart-app-banner as a dependency of itself

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I tried to build the source of: https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner

With:

```
npm install --save smart-app-banner
```

but I get:

```
npm WARN install Refusing to install smart-app-banner as a dependency of itself
```

**What is wrong here? How can I compile the source?**

Comment: Where are you running this command? I make a new empty directory, ran `npm install --save smart-app-banner`, and it worked (added a `node_modules` folder containing `smart-app-banner`, which contained the source), though since there was no `package.json` file there the `--save` flag did nothing.

Comment: @Timespace I don't get it. I want to download the source. Modify it and compile the modified source. How can I do that?

Comment: Right, gotcha. The installation instructions on that page are assuming that you want to include it in an existing project. To pull the source directly from GitHub you can fork it (needs a free account) then clone it locally. It...looks like they've done something a bit odd, though - the file `smart-app-banner.js` looks like it was just a minified version of `index.js` up until a month ago, but now it's a minified version of something else entirely, with no hint as to what the source is.

Comment: @Timespace sending pull requests I assume that it is a compile of index.js. So how do I compile it?

Comment: Looking at the pull requests that other people have made - they've only touched `index.js`, and left `smart-app-banner.js` unchanged. I have no idea how the owner has minified it - there are many ways of doing it, and there's no hint in the repository to point to which way they chose. If you'd like to make a pull request, I'd advise making the changes, making the request and ask the repository owner in that request if they'd like you to update `smart-app-banner.js`, and if so, how.

Answer (score 0):

`$ mkdir smart-app-banner`

`$ cd smart-app-banner`

`$ npm init`

Now, your package.json has a "name" : "smart-app-banner" property

When doing npm install smart-app-banner, NPM thinks you are trying to install the package in itself, because of that name.

> Edit : Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267707/npm-warn-install-refusing-to-install-hapi-as-a-dependency-of-itself)

Comment: How does this answer help. I want to compile the source from here: https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner How do I do that?