# Unable to install *sequelize* using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js

I am unable to install `sequelize` using npm. When I am trying getting following error. I am using node version `v5.4.1` and npm version `3.3.12`.[image]

can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Your command is wrong.. try for this: sudo npm install sequelize --save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267707/npm-warn-install-refusing-to-install-hapi-as-a-dependency-of-itself)

Your module name contains `sequelize` key word and you should change it in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize

Hopefully the procedure on the link will help you installing sequelize

Or try this

> $ npm install --save sequelize
>
> ## And one of the following: $ npm install --save pg pg-hstore $ npm install --save mysql // For both mysql and mariadb dialects $ npm
>
> install --save sqlite3 $ npm install --save tedious // MSSQL

Comment: I have seen the link, I didn't find anything . In case if you find anything, can you suggest me.