# centos7 , Why i can not install express into my server?

Tags: node.js, npm

First i install node js

sccess to application dir

```
cd /home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html
```

Download file

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.1/node-v8.11.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Extract File

```
tar xvf node-v8.11.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Rename to nodejs

```
mv node-v8.11.1-linux-x64 nodejs
```

Install

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ cp nodejs/bin/node ~/bin
$ cd ~/bin
$ ln -s ../nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm
```

Then check version

```
$ node --version
```

Get `v6.3.1`

and

```
$ npm --version
```

Get `3.10.3`

going to main dir

```
cd
```

.............................

Then install express

sccess to application dir

```
cd /home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html
```

create package.json

```
npm init
```

by `entry point: (index.js)`

Install express

```
$ npm install express --save
```

But i get error

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/v6.3.1/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/v6.3.1/bin/npm" "install" "express" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install express as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/nodejs/npm-debug.log
```

How can i do ?

Comment: Did you use the name "express" in your package.json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN install Refusing to install hapi as a dependency of itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267707/npm-warn-install-refusing-to-install-hapi-as-a-dependency-of-itself)

Comment: yes , name express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @jonrsharpe you cannot use have same name for your project (name attribute in your package.json) as that of a package that you are trying to install.

The error code **ENOSELF** (read as e no self) and the message

> Refusing to install express as a **dependency of itself**

can help you figure out in future if you are facing this type of issue.